# Understanding SQL Case Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get a better understanding of how the SQL Case Function works.

Say for example I have the following code in a query and value1 = 'ABCDE'

```
SELECT CASE ColumnName
           WHEN value1 LIKE '%ABC%' THEN 'Hello'
           WHEN value1 LIKE '%CDE%' THEN 'World'
           ELSE 'Nothing'
       END AS Answer
FROM TableName
```

I am confused by what this code will return.

I would assume from reading it should return HelloWorld, but having ran a similar query I have found it only returns Hello.

Can anyone explain why this is ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CASE` expression consists of a series of `WHEN`/`THEN` clauses.  Each clause tests a condition.

The `CASE` expression stops at the *first* `WHEN` condition that evaluates to true and returns the `THEN` value.  In your example, that would be "Hello".

Note:  The `ColumnName` after `CASE` is a syntax error, if you have conditions in the `WHEN` clauses.  I assume this is a typo because your query returns something.

If you want the values concatenated, then use an expression such as:

```
SELECT ((CASE WHEN value1 LIKE '%ABC%' THEN 'Hello' ELSE '' END) +
        (CASE WHEN value1 LIKE '%CDE%' THEN 'World' ELSE '' END)
       ) AS Answer
FROM TableName;
```

Comment: I'd better say "The `ColumnName` after `CASE` and `predicate` after `WHEN` at the same time is a syntax error."

Comment: @Gordon Linoff please check this https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/690017/case-coalesce-wont-always-evaluate-in-textual-order

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma . . . I agree that is probably an error.  But the issue is what the `case` returns.  If you interpret "short-circuiting" loosely, then all the expressions can be evaluated before anything is returned . . . and these could return an error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So if the first statement is found to be true does it then skip the others? Or does it compare the others as well ??